# Removing spaces from tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, strip

I have this list:

```
[('', '', '654', 'Tom', '- Jerry', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', '', '', '756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'), 
 ('453', 'Hulk - Superman', '', '', '', '', '', '')]
```

How do I remove the unneeded (mostly outer) characters so that it remains something like this:

```
[('654', 'Tom' , '- Jerry'), 
 ('756', 'X-man' -', Batman'),
 ('435','Hulk - Superman')]
```

It's a tuple so I guess I can't use the `.strip()` method

Thanks.

Comment: `'Tom' - 'Jerry'` isn't a valid Python expression (nor are the other examples you give with dashes)

Comment: I know, was in a hurry. thanks guys

Comment: You can't use a hyphen between two elements of a tuple. You will have to make that a different element of the tuple.

Answer (score 6):

Use `filter()`; it removes `empty' (falsey) values by default:

```
[tuple(filter(None, tp)) for tp in inputlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [tuple(filter(None, tp)) for tp in inputlist]
[('654', 'Tom', '- Jerry'), ('756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'), ('453', 'Hulk - Superman')]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
>>> t = [('', '', '654', 'Tom', '- Jerry', '', '', ''),
         ('', '', '', '', '', '756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'),
         ('453', 'Hulk - Superman', '', '', '', '', '', '')]

>>> [tuple(filter(None, i)) for i in t]
[('654', 'Tom', '- Jerry'), ('756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'), ('453', 'Hulk - Superman')]
```

`filter(None, i)` removes any `False`-ish value in `i`, leaving you with only the strings that are non-empty.

---

`0`, `False`, `None` and any empty container (eg `[]`, `''`, etc) are `False`-ish values.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get rid of the empty strings, I'd recommend a filter:

```
In [4]: myList = [('', '', '654', 'Tom', '- Jerry', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', '756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'), ('453', 'Hulk - Superman', '', '', '', '', '', '')]

In [5]: [tuple(itertools.ifilter(None, t)) for t in myList]
Out[5]: 
[('654', 'Tom', '- Jerry'),
 ('756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'),
 ('453', 'Hulk - Superman')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code with your list and it is working:

```
list1 = [('', '', '654', 'Tom', '- Jerry', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', '756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'), ('453', 'Hulk - Superman', '', '', '', '', '', '')]  ##you can add the elements as you want
tuple2 =()
for i in range(len(list1)):
   if type(list1[i]) == tuple:
       k = 0
       for e in list1[i]:
           if not e == ' ' and not e == '':
               tuple2 = tuple2 + (e,)
               k+=1

       list1[i] = tuple2

print list1
```

What it does is:

1. It checks if the type of the element is a tuple
2. Then for all the elements in the tuple, if it is a space then it is ignored
   else it is added to the tuple
3. Finally this is assigned in place of the previous tuple

This is the output that I got:

```
>>> list1
[('654', 'Tom', '- Jerry'), ('654', 'Tom', '- Jerry', '756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman'), ('654', 'Tom', '- Jerry', '756', 'X-Man -', 'Batman', '453', 'Hulk - Superman')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this short thing...

```
lst = [tuple(i for i in tpl if i) for tpl in lst]
```